# What is the modern way of creating eventbus using RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java2, event-bus

In my previous project I have used Otto EventBus for fragment to activity communications, sticky events for nested fragments and activities and also to process push notifications.

For upcoming projects I wanted to make use of RxJava2 and build eventbus using it. I wanted to know what is the modern way of doing it as the blogs and repos  related to these are old.

Findings about it till now:

1. EventBus libraries are deprecated in favour of RxJava (Okay)
2. Creating eventbus using RxJava is simple. (Okay) https://blog.kaush.co/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus/
3. Use RxRelays not just Rx Subject (Okay)
4. RxRelay repository states that when your app becomes more and more reactive, you would not need RxRelay (!!)

What is the modern way of achieving eventbus pattern that can also handle sticky events in RxJava2. Should eventbus pattern at all be used in a RxAndroid world. Are there alternative approaches to eventbus pattern?

Comment: Yes, I have used it in some of my pet projects. I have a common scenario. For example, I have a retrofit interceptor to intercept request and response and if anything is wrong with the request or response. I used to send a session expired sticky event and any activity navigated after that would log out of the app. Modelling live data to solve this problem may be bit of overkill.

Comment: By not doing it. Using the same "funnel" for all your data will create a choke point in your application. Most sequences are independent in practice and there is no use to try and sent through one pipe while wasting time to filter out into idividual flows again. Use one flow and combinators if you need interplay between them.

Comment: Probably, I did not understand the context. When you said "By not doing it" , you mean not to use eventbus pattern at all?

Comment: That's right, using an event-bus based structure is wasteful at minimum. I'd consider it a remnant from the pre-reactive programming times where moving between threads back and forth required too many boilerplate and having a bus that always leads back to the main thread was more convenient. This is no longer necessary as RxJava gives you scheduling as a parameter so you can return to the main thread from any flow.

Comment: okay. I will have to read up more on this to understand I guess. If you can share any links which shows how using rxjava can avoid eventbus patterns(examples), that will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I found this discussion, It is relevant to this topic. If it is useful to anyone else. https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay/issues/7

Answer (score 0):

One of the most powerful architectures for handling events and state in a reactive world is [flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html). It borrows a lot from event busses but adds some neat stuff on top of it.

Not only does it solve the "stickyness" problem but also allows you to maintain state between configuration changes and between different screens (activities or fragments) in a deterministic and easily testable way.

[This](https://medium.com/@zeyad.gasser/reactive-redux-simply-managing-state-with-rxjava-8d6b25849068) is a pretty good article to get you started, but there are also a bunch of libraries out there that aim to simplify it for you (I'm building one of these myself)

Comment: Flux is for Web development. The question is about Android and RxJava.

Comment: @CommonsWare Flux is just a pattern. Lots of people are using for all kinds of applications including web and mobile. It might be largest in the javascript/react world because redux was the first popular implementation of it, but it works amazingly well on native android too.